# Two Views with autocomplete filters display no result

Tags: ajax

I have 2 views-blocks with autocomplete filters, both filters are for the title field. And autocomplete filters display no result when the views are placed on the same page. 
How to make them to not conflict with each other?

I use this module [Views Autocomplete Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_autocomplete_filters)

Comment: I think, we need some more details of what you're trying to achieve and how your views are set up.

Comment: this may help you https://www.drupal.org/node/1392366

Comment: I think you have selected **equal to** operator instead of **contains** operator. Also please check if you are using ajax than you can use same field name under **More** option else you need to change that and need to be seperate.

Comment: It's set **contains** on both and ajax is also switched on

Comment: Ok, than try with changing the fields name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link provided by  **WaQaR Ali** solved the problem.

> The problem lies in the fact that two form-fields get the same ID.
>   Placing this code in a hook_form_FORM_ID_alter():

```
<?php
 $form['title']['#id'] = 'form-text-' . rand(0,100); 
?>
```

Thank you Ali!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue by

1-clicking on your filter (in the view UI, under 'Filtering criteria')

2-Then scroll down in the opened window until you can open the "more" fieldset

3-Change the Filter ID to make it unique.. I mean if you can't have 2 block view on the same page with the same filter ID